# C++20 constexpr std::copy optimizations for run-time

Tags: c++, optimization, constexpr, c++20

[cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) says:

> In practice, implementations of std::copy avoid multiple assignments and use bulk copy functions such as std::memmove if the value type is TriviallyCopyable

However, the page also states that the overloads which don't take an execution policy will be `constexpr` since C++20. Will the standard forbid these run-time optimizations (since `std::memmove` is not constexpr) or is there a way to optimize `constexpr` functions for run-time?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

We can have our cake and eat it to, too.

Let's just consider the simplest specialization of `copy`, the one that copies `char`s. In C++17, that might look like:

```
char* copy(char const* first, char const* last, char* d)
{
    memcpy(d, first, last - first);
    return d + (last - first);
}
```

Of course, we can't just slap `constexpr` on that because `memcpy` isn't a constexpr function, that won't work. But it only doesn't work during constant evaluation. What we need is a way to conditionally use `memcpy` if we're at runtime.

We have such a thing in C++20, [`std::is_constant_evaluated()`](https://wg21.link/p0595):

```
constexpr char* copy(char const* first, char const* last, char* d)
{
    if (std::is_constant_evaluated()) {
        while (first != last) {
            *d++ = *first++;
        }
        return d;       
    } else {
        memcpy(d, first, last - first);
        return d + (last - first);
    }
}
```

And now we have an algorithm that does the efficient thing at runtime but still works during constexpr evaluation time.

---

Note: It is `if (std::is_constant_evaluated())`, *never* `if constexpr (std::is_constant_evaluated())`. The later is equivalent to `if constexpr (true) { ... }`. gcc 10.1 will start warning on this erroneous usage.

Comment: How does this compile without `if constexpr`?  I don't see why the compiler should be allowed to discard the `else` branch, unless `if (std::is_constant_evaluated())` is treated special.

Comment: @HenriMenke It's not the _existence_ of `memcpy` that is a problem for constant evaluation, it's the _use_ of it. All the rules of constant evaluation are "you cannot run this code," not "you cannot have it in your function." e.g. in `constexpr int f(bool b) { return b ? throw 0 : 0; }`, `f(false)` is perfectly fine. The `throw` only breaks if we reach it.

Comment: Wouldn't any decent compiler be smart enough to optimize the first loop to same as using `memcpy`? Haven't looked at compile output of this kind of code, so maybe I am overly optimistic about compilers' ability to optimize.

Comment: @hyde Even if they could there are still people asking for fast debug builds, which is why we still have a bunch of optimizations on the library side instead of always relying on the optimizer.