# cout is able to run at compile-time

Tags: c++, constexpr, constexpr-function

I think `cout` is only allowed to run at runtime but the following code proves otherwise. Or am I not understanding something deeper? I only expected it to print the message once, but it printed twice. Why is that?

```
import std;

constexpr void logError(const std::string& error);

constexpr int sqrt(int x)
{
    if (x < 0)
    {
        logError("Oh no, this can't be real...");
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        int result{ 1 };
        while (result * result <= x) ++result;
        return result - 1;
    }
}

int c = sqrt(-1);

int main()
{
    sqrt(-1);
   
}

constexpr void logError(const std::string& error)
{
    if (!std::is_constant_evaluated())
        std::cout << error << std::endl;
}
```

I think this code `int c = sqrt(-1);` calls logError, but it is not allowed, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

> I think `cout` is only allowed to run at runtime but the following code proves otherwise. Or am I not understanding something deeper?

You're right about `std::cout`. You just misunderstand how `constexpr` relates to compile-time evaluation.

`constexpr` doesn't mean that `logError` is run at compile-time.
It merely means that the function *can possibly* run at compile-time, if needed.

> ```cpp
> int c = sqrt(-1);
> ```

... is not a case where a constant expression is required to initialize `c`, so `sqrt(-1)` as run at run-time.
See also [When does a constexpr function get evaluated at compile time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14248235/5740428)

Furthermore, it would be safe to run `logError` at compile-time because the check for `std::is_constant_evaluated()` ensures that `std::cout <<` isn't done within a constant expression.
See [C++20 constexpr std::copy optimizations for run-time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57609048/5740428) for an example of how it's typically used.

#### Further notes

It's not a good idea to split `constexpr` functions into declaration and definition like you've done.
A `constexpr` function can only be used within a a constant expression once it's been defined.
See also [Use of constexpr function before definition fails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29434650/5740428)

Comment: I followed your recommendation and removed the declaration for logError. Now the code runs correctly with a single message printed. Do you know why?

Comment: @ntos you don't need a declaration of a function prior to its definition in general. Why wouldn't it work, and what's your current code?

Comment: I deleted the definition of `logError` and placed its definition above `sqrt`. Now only a single message is printed. So as long as the definition of `logError` is after `main` the initialization of `c` is done at runtime. Do you know any docs about initialization of global variables with a function?

Comment: @ntos can't reproduce https://godbolt.org/z/GT3bY8Eb1 . The compiler can't just arbitrarily constant-evaluate functions when it wants to. Maybe you've made it `const int`, which changes that though.

Comment: Please write it like this ` constexpr void logError(const std::string& error;  int c = sqrt(-1); int main(){ } constexpr void logError(const std::string& error){if (!(std::is_constant_evaluated())) ... }}` . As you can see I keep `c` a normal int. The definition of `logError` after an empty `main`. The message will appear. Place the definition before `main` and the message will disappear. Strange.

Comment: Here is the link to the result: https://godbolt.org/z/PsEnWv9ah. Looking at the assembly code, mind you I am a noob, `main` runs and returns  before `c` is initialized. I think `cout` must run inside `main`. This is strange.

Comment: @ntos no, the message is printed during dynamic initialization, before `main` runs.

Comment: Are you sure? Could you give me a link about `cout` running outside of `main`. This is madness.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4783404/5740428

Comment: Thank you so much. c++ is crazy as hell.